# How do you say this in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to alert something if the user's mouse has left TWO html elements (a textfield as well as a span block). How do I say the **AND** in jquery, in vain I tried something like this:

```
if ($('textarea.commentField') && $('span.loginPrompt')).mouseout(function() {
     alert('something');
});
```

Comment: Just a point about JavaScript syntax - that snippet makes no sense at all, as you may have noticed from how it doesn't work. It would translate to 'if $('textarea.commentField') and also $('span.loginPrompt') evaluate to boolean true, oh wait, we're trying to run a method on the if condition... which is a boolean, and has no methods, but aha, Javascript expects a { or a single statement here... WHAT? Oh, syntax error'.

Comment: I suggest describing the actual feature you want rather than how you are trying to implement it.  If you describe the feature, it's likely we'll be able to give you a better solution than simply giving you a way to implement an **AND** between two events in jQuery.

Comment: I'd say you must give html mark up... there has to be a better way to do that and it depends on your html..

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this natively, as this will require some legwork.

Something like this would work, but there must be a better solution:

```
var state = {a:false,b:false};
$('.a').mouseenter(enterA);
$('.a').mouseout(exitA);
$('.b').mouseenter(enterB);
$('.b').mouseout(exitB);

function enterA(){ state.a = true }
function exitA(){ state.a = false }
function enterB(){ state.b = true }
function exitB(){ state.b = false }
```

And then if you have jQuery 1.4.2, you can bind multiple events, so add these after the first events.

```
$('.a,.b').mouseout(function(){ 
//we're outside of both blocks
if( !state.a && !state.b )
{
   //do something
}
});
```

This will then fire when you've left A or B, and you're also outside of the other one. I think this is what you meant.

Comment: There has to be a better way, though. Sanity dictates such :P.

Comment: If one element is inside the other in your markup, then only the parent element needs the event. If you were attaching a mouseenter, you would need to attach it to the child.

Comment: What if they overlap, but aren't 100% contained? Consider two absolute positioned divs that interlock. I assume there's some crazy UI stuff going on here.

Comment: If they're completely independent in the markup, then yeah you'd need the above code, but if you're overlapping two elements, why not just absolutely position one relative to (and inside) the other? It's hard to say without seeing the markup, but in general if it takes nasty workarounds to do what you're trying to do, you're probably doing it the hard way.

Comment: But yes, if A contains B, then only A needs to be considered, and then you only need to use $('.a').mouseout.

Comment: @Bennor: Probably. You never know what kind of control someone has over markup, though, or the reasoning for such. The question seemed to imply that only using the container element wouldn't work, or at least that's the only way in which the question makes sense. $('.a').mouseout may very well be the only thing necessary.

Comment: Yeah, fair call. I just assumed that because of the poor wording of the question, the obvious and simplest solution hadn't been tried. Without a good understanding of HTML, it's possible to overlook the fact that if a wraps b in the markup then even if part of b is rendered outside of a it's still considered to be in inside a as far as mouse events are concerned.

Comment: Gaaaaah. Where's the feedback from the OP?

Answer (score 3):

If the span encloses the textfield, you will only need the handler on the span.

If you want to attach the same handler to two independent elements, use this:

```
$('textarea.commentField, span.loginPrompt').mouseout(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
$('textarea.commentField, span.loginPrompt').mouseout(function() {
     alert('something');
});
```

Comment: That would mean if it leaves either one, it would alert that. So you'd probably get two.

Comment: This will only attach it to a textarea with the class commentField INSIDE a span with the class loginPrompt.

Comment: Actually, this wouldn't do much, since span.loginPrompt is used as "context" for the selector. the comma needs to be within the single quotes.

Comment: @Marko, You're right... thanks for pointing that out... Editing to correct it to the way I meant it...

Comment: @Bennor McCarthy no, it would bind it to two separate elements (or as many as match the two selectors). Note how they are separately enclosed in quotes and have a comma between them. What you are saying would be $('span.loginPrompt textarea.commentField ')

Comment: Ah, classic bait & switch. My comment was based on the original code which was: $('textarea.commentField', 'span.loginPrompt').mouseout(...)

Comment: @Bennor, my apologies... I was just correcting my wrong answer. And yes, your original comment was spot on with the incorrect answer that I edited out as seen here - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3723049/revisions

Comment: Not your fault mate, just the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the other answers, you could try

```
(function() {
  var inc = 0;
  var both = false;
  $('textarea.commentField, span.loginPrompt')
    .mouseover(function() {
      inc++;
      if(inc==2) { both = true; }
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
      inc--;
      if(inc == 0 && both) {
        both = false; 
        // do whatever else you wanted here
    });
})();
```

This differs in functionality from the other state-based answer, in that the `do whatever` bit will be triggered only when the mouse has been inside both the `textarea` and the `span` simultaneously. The `both` var tracks whether, at any time, both elements have had the mouse enter without leaving either.

It's wrapped in a function so the state vars don't pollute the exterior namespace